# input type file hidden when using tinymce mobile

Tags: tinymce

I am using Tinymce for a textarea. I also have a input type file on the same page. On a mobile device Tinymce hides the input type="file". Is there any way to tell Tinymce not to hide the input?

I can do a workaround by using the label, wrapping it around an image for the user to click to browse, but then it doesn't display the selected file name as it normally would. Unless there is a way to show the selected filename. Otherwise the user clicks and selects the file and nowhere does it actually show the user that a file was selected. I would prefer just having the normal "choose file" display for type="file".

```
 <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
 <form>
 <textarea id="something" rows="3"></textarea> 
 <input type="file" id="thefile" accept="image/*">
 <button type="submit" id="submitbutton">Save</button>
 </form> 
 <script>
 tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 400,
  menubar: false,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime table paste code help wordcount'
  ],
  toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft 
  aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | 
  removeformat | help',
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsing around I saw someone opened an issue on [Github](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4149) about this bug (still shipped within the Version: 5.0.15 (2019-09-02)), which is caused by the *mobile* CSS: **skins\ui\oxide-dark\skin.mobile.min.css**.

By overriding the property *webkit* "visibility" for *input file* in your own CSS, it is working:

```
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
     display: block;
}
```

It's better to do this in your own CSS, in order to leave TinyMCE CSS as is, in case of future update.

Hope this helps you.